# google plus api, people search by location

Tags: api, google-plus

I'm looking for documentation on how to format a query for the [Google Plus People search API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/search). Specifically how to `search by location`, in addition to using keywords.

I would also be great to know how to search for keywords with AND OR logic.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is currently no way to do this.  [Google Plus People Search](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/search) searches on displayName

You can test this by going to the bottom and using the try me:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people?query=denmark&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Authorization:  Bearer ya29.yQAdQCMab-MuerpNcx-dImbA0fBPxfsJbzYo9W0zA2rPKxG0oSNOh9MlarI9BD2EhVAQLHQiqdsWNg
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

200 OK
 - Show headers -

 {
 "kind": "plus#peopleFeed",
 "etag": "\"RqKWnRU4WW46-6W3rWhLR9iFZQM/CQs9-i31YgOHOFErObqjjPpqvac\"",
 "selfLink": "https://content.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people?query=denmark&key=AIzaSyCFj15TpkchL4OUhLD1Q2zgxQnMb7v3XaM",
 "title": "Google+ People Search Results",
 "nextPageToken": "EBkaAA",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "plus#person",
   "etag": "\"RqKWnRU4WW46-6W3rWhLR9iFZQM/dvmOjlS_L11y3FImcrvga14_MPI\"",
   "objectType": "page",
   "id": "107491210485921364379",
   "displayName": "Denmark.dk - The official website of Denmark",
   "url": "https://plus.google.com/+denmark",
   "image": {
    "url": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-mBlKA4p0ZYQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAOE/PxZ_m7uQ1LM/photo.jpg?sz=50"

   }


  },

  {
   "kind": "plus#person",
   "etag": "\"RqKWnRU4WW46-6W3rWhLR9iFZQM/wAHGx7MwIQSVIJftHeGgFMiK7Uc\"",
   "objectType": "person",
   "id": "102142746546626575404",
   "displayName": "Alumeco Denmark",
   "url": "https://plus.google.com/102142746546626575404",
   "image": {
    "url": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-L9Tg78K2IVU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAsU/qaJ2thgrfio/photo.jpg?sz=50"

   }


  }}
```

As you can see it is returning people who have Denmark in there display name.   A feature request has been made for this.  https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=693